# Material UI changing states onClick of the individual item from the ItemList

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

Having an issue with selected props that comes from material UI. I'm trying to have a single item selected when clicked from my list, but right now when I click on any of items both of them go "selected".

Hope that's quite clear.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    ListItem,
    ListItemIcon,
    List,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import navLinks from 'components/navLinks';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const simpleList= () => {
    const [select, setSelect] = useState(false);

    const setActive = () => {
        setSelect(true);
    };

    return (
        <List>
            {navLinks.map((item) => (
                <div
                    key={item.id}
                >
                    <Link
                        className="simple-menu-link"
                        to={item.url}
                    >
                        <ListItem
                            button
                            key={item.id}
                            selected={select}
                            onClick={(e) => { setActive(e); }}
                        >
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                {item.icon}
                            </ListItemIcon>
                        </ListItem>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            ))}
        </List>
    );
};

export default simpleList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, each `ListItem` is reading from the `select` state. That way, if `select` is `true`, then all `ListItem` are selected. Same if it is false.

Since you need only one `ListItem` to be selected, you can instead store the index of that particular `ListItem` in the state.

Try something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    ListItem,
    ListItemIcon,
    List,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import navLinks from 'components/navLinks';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const simpleList= () => {
    // setting initial index as null so that nothing is selected.
    // If you want first index to be selected, set initial state as 0
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(null);

    const setActive = (index) => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    };

    return (
        <List>
            {navLinks.map((item, index) => (
                <div
                    key={item.id}
                >
                    <Link
                        className="simple-menu-link"
                        to={item.url}
                    >
                        <ListItem
                            button
                            key={item.id}
                            selected={index === selectedIndex}
                            onClick={() => { setActive(index); }}
                        >
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                {item.icon}
                            </ListItemIcon>
                        </ListItem>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            ))}
        </List>
    );
};

export default simpleList;
```

Comment: Great. Can you please mark this as the correct answer? Will help future reader too :)